# Assigning Operators to embedded Class Functions

Tags: python, function, class

I am working on a homework assignment for my introductory python class.
The goal is to define functions to use * / + - < > <= >= operators with class calls. This particular program takes 3 parameters `self, inches, numerator, denominator` and stores the denominator as a factor of 64 (if it can be simplified)

The call `RulerUnit(2, 1, 4)` would return `"2 1/4"`

I am working on the multiplication part, and am having trouble when `inches` is equal to `0`

Is `inches == 0` or `inches is None`?

Furthermore, whichever the case may be, when I perform an assertion such as:
`assert(str(RulerUnit(2, 3, 4) * RulerUnit(0, 1, 2)) == "1 3/8")`

An `AssertionError` is rased, my code

`print((RulerUnit(2, 3, 4) * RulerUnit(0, 1, 2)))`

prints `2 3/8`

Code:

```
def __mul__ (self, other):

    if self.inches == 0 and other.inches == 0:
        newnum = self.num * other.num
        finaldenom = self.denom * other.denom
        finalnum = newnum % 64
        finalinches = newnum // finaldenom
        return RulerUnit(finalinches, finalnum, finaldenom)

    elif self.inches == 0 and other.inches != 0:
        newnum1 = (self.inches * self.denom) + self.num
        finaldenom = self.denom * other.denom
        finalnum = (newnum1 * other.num) % 64
        finalinches = (newnum1 * other.num) // finaldenom
        return RulerUnit(finalinches, finalnum, finaldenom)

    elif self.inches!= 0 and other.inches == 0:
        newnum1 = (self.inches * self.denom) + self.num
        finaldenom = self.denom * other.denom
        finalnum = (newnum1 * other.num) % 64
        finalinches = (newnum1 * other.num) // finaldenom
        return RulerUnit(finalinches, finalnum, finaldenom)

    elif self.inches != 0 and other.inches != 0:
        newnum1 = (self.inches * self.denom) + self.num
        newnum2 = (other.inches * other.denom) + other.num
        finaldenom = (self.denom * other.denom) % 64
        finalnum = (newnum1 * newnum2) % 64
        finalinches = (newnum1 * newnum2) // finaldenom
        return RulerUnit(finalinches, finalnum, finaldenom)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for special cases when the `inches` part of one of your values is zero. You can just use the zero in the computation, and it should work out right:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    num = (self.inches * self.denom + self.num) * (other.inches * other.denom + other.num)
    denom = self.denom * other.denom
    inches, num = divmod(num, denom)
    return RulerUnit(inches, num, denom)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize how you store the values. 2 3/8 is really 19/8. Once you do that, math is trivial. Use mixed numbers for input and output, but use pure fractions internally.

```
class Ruler:
    def __init__(self, inches, n, d):
        self.n = inches*d + n
        self.d = d

    def __str__(self):
        inches, n = divmod(self.n, d)
        return "{} {}/{}".format(inches, n, self.d)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Ruler(0, self.n * other.n, self.d * other.d)
```